# How to flip UIImage horizontally with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, flip

The solution to do UIImage flipping is with the Objective-C code:

```
[UIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationDownMirrored]
```

However, imageWithCGImage is not available in Swift! Is there a solution for flipping image horizontally with Swift? Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Most factory methods are converted to initializers in swift. Whenever available, even if the class method is still available, they are preferred. You can use:

```
    init(CGImage cgImage: CGImage!, scale: CGFloat, orientation: UIImageOrientation)
```

The usage would look like this:

```
var image = UIImage(CGImage: img.CGImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: .DownMirrored)
```

Swift 5

```
var image = UIImage(cgImage: img.cgImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: .downMirrored)
```

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't seem to flip the image.  Is there a way to respect the orientation when rendering? `public extension UIImage {
 var flippedHorizontally: UIImage {
  return UIImage(CGImage: self.CGImage!, scale: self.scale, orientation: .UpMirrored)
 }
}`

Comment: Oh... I was using the .LeftMirrored option for selfie photos. It works well to display the photo after the flipping. However, the photo is upside down after saving to photo album. Any ideas?

Comment: @Gujamin, that extension worked perfectly. I converted it into Swift 3 syntax and was able to swap the image of a UIButton with no problem. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is wrong. When I create `UIBarButtonItem` with the original image its scale is normal. But when I use your method image becomes huge! Note: I don't apply any transformations to an image other than your one - just assign it to bar button item

Answer (score 51):

For me the simplest way was to use the `.withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation()` instance method of `UIImage` as follows:

`let flippedImage = straightImage.withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation()`

Simple one-liners always make me happy :)

Comment: Brilliant, but does not respect the vertical orientations for images captured from AVFoundation- flips the image upside down

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to adjust this after the `withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation()`?

Comment: #available(iOS 10.0, *)

Comment: this seems to have a significant performance hit for me on MacOS. Fine if my image is small and/or I'm doing it occasionally, but if it needs to be responsive maybe not.

Answer (score 33):

In Swift.... (6.3.1)

```
YourUIImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)
```

This also works with a UIView

Comment: This is not for flipping a `UIImage`, but for flipping `UIImageView`.

Comment: It's not flipping UIImage. But it solves my UI issues.

Comment: not all UI elements are derived from `UIView` so they haven't `transform` property (like `UIBarButtonItem`)

Answer (score 18):

Changing image orientation parameter is not actually flipping the image in all cases. Image must be redrawn somehow... For example like this:

**Swift 3**

```
func flipImageLeftRight(_ image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, image.scale)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.translateBy(x: image.size.width, y: image.size.height)
    context.scaleBy(x: -image.scale, y: -image.scale)

    context.draw(image.cgImage!, in: CGRect(origin:CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Comment: 1)why do you scale by x and y simultaneously?
2)when I assign the image result from your function it disappears in `UIBarButtonItem`

Answer (score 15):

## Swift 5 Solution

Here is the simplest solution for actually flipping the image

```
extension UIImage {
    func flipHorizontally() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        
        context.translateBy(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
        context.scaleBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)
        context.translateBy(x: -self.size.width/2, y: -self.size.height/2)
        
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
        
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return newImage
    }
}
```

and to use this solution you can do the following

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image.png")!
let newImage = image.flipHorizontally()
```

Comment: This create black background image instead of transparent . Please take note

Comment: @RajuyourPepe I have updated the answer to allow for transparency. Thank you!

Comment: Great Answer! For anyone wondering, if you want to flip the image vertically just change `context.scaleBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)` to `context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)`.

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 4**

```
YOURIMAGEVIEW.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
```

This might also be handy:

```
YOURIMAGE.imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection()
```

Comment: The question is about UIImage, not UIImageView

Comment: This is not correct answer but in other condition it works for me thanks

Answer (score 2):

**To flip image in swift 4**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var first = 1
var second = 1

@IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func flip1(_ sender: Any) {

    if first == 1 {
        img.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
        first = 2
    }
    else if first == 2
    {
        img.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: +1, y: 1)
        first = 1
    }

}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

If your use case requires saving the `UIImage` after transforming, it will need to be drawn into a new `CGContext`.

```
extension UIImage {
  
  enum Axis {
    case horizontal, vertical
  }
  
  func flipped(_ axis: Axis) -> UIImage {
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
    
    return renderer.image {
      let context = $0.cgContext
      context.translateBy(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
      
      switch axis {
      case .horizontal:
        context.scaleBy(x: -1, y: 1)
      case .vertical:
        context.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
      }
      
      context.translateBy(x: -size.width / 2, y: -size.height / 2)
      
      draw(at: .zero)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Used it:             imgClone.image = pickedImage.flipped(.vertical)

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of similar questions on SO. And I believe it's worth to post solution using `CoreImage` here too.

Please note: when getting final `UIImage`, it's necessary to convert to `CGImage` first to respect extent of `CIImage`

```
extension UIImage {
    func imageRotated(by degrees: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

        let orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation(imageOrientation)
        // Create CIImage respecting image's orientation 
        guard let inputImage = CIImage(image: self)?.oriented(orientation) 
            else { return self }

        // Flip the image itself
        let flip = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
        let outputImage = inputImage.transformed(by: flip)

        // Create CGImage first
        guard let cgImage = CIContext().createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) 
            else { return self }

        // Create output UIImage from CGImage
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: `Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage.Orientation' to expected argument type 'UInt32'`