# How to change orientation of image after capture?

Tags: ios, swift

This is code which i used in my custom camera for capture photo but it capturing photo correctly but if suppose user rotate device(but camera will still in portrait like iphone camera) and take picture i want that picture in portrait.how can i do that?

```
        let stillImageOutput = self._getStillImageOutput()

        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {

     //   videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait

        stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection , completionHandler: { [weak self] sample, error in

            if let error = error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self?._show(NSLocalizedString("Error", comment:""), message: error.localizedDescription)
                })
                imageCompletion(nil,error as NSError?)
                return
            }

            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sample)

             var capturedImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)[![This how photo showing if i capture by rotating Device][1]][1]
```

[image: This image i want in portrait]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flip UIImage horizontally with Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965638/how-to-flip-uiimage-horizontally-with-swift)

Comment: Nope.it's different question.

Comment: This might help. It's in Objective-C but you get the idea. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7932657/7005670

Answer (score 3):

add below code after the initialization of  videoConnection and you good to go

```
switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
                case .landscapeLeft:
                    videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight
                    break
                case .landscapeRight:
                    videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeLeft
                    break
                case .portrait:
                     videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                    break
                case .portraitUpsideDown:
                    videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portraitUpsideDown
                    break
                default:
                    videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                    break
                }
```

Comment: OMG! The `landscapeLeft ` and `landscapeRight ` orientations don't match! Makes me feel a little better about inconsistencies in my code I guess.

Answer (score -1):

Set the orientation before capturing the image

```swift
// set the image orientation in output
  if let photoOutputConnection = self.photoOutput.connection(with: .video) {
        photoOutputConnection.videoOrientation = videoPreviewLayerOrientation! // set the orientation you want
    }

self.photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: photoCaptureProcessor) // capture image
```